# Telegram Api usage understading

Tags: android, telegram, telegram-bot

How to use telegram api auth.sendInvites, I have searched a lot on web, but didn't get any useful information. You will find telegram methods from https://core.telegram.org/methods site.

I have already checked https://core.telegram.org/api link, but they don't give any exact/proper guide/explanation.

I got sourcode from git repo DrKLO-Telegram.

I want to modify the source code to make custom telegram app, so help me how to use `auth.sendInvites` api in Telegram.

Answer (score 0):

The method you need is https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.sendInvites

See below.

```
auth.sendInvites#771c1d97 phone_numbers:Vector<string> message:string = Bool;
```

Note that you need to successful Authorize and Authenticate your telegram account in your new application before you can use this API method.

Also you would need a TL parser to encode the request, then encrypt and send it to Telegram Servers. There are a few libraries out there to get you started, ultimately you could write your own.

For an up-to-date list of other Telegram Functions & Schema check [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/master/Telegram/SourceFiles/mtproto/scheme.tl)